# A recursive definition for a 2-dimensional array in SAS

Tags: arrays, sas

Let $n>0$ be an integer, 
and let $r_1$ be a vector of length $n$, $r_1 = r_{1,1},r_{1,2},\dots,r_{1,n}$.

I want to define, for $1 < i \le j \le n$, 
$$r_{i,j} = \frac{r_{i-1,j}}{1-r_{i-1,i-1}}\,.$$

How to do this in SAS? Assume $n$ is defined as a macro variable.
I am not sure how to enter the initial vector $r_1$, 
but let's assume we have that. For the recursive part I was thinking along the lines:

```
array r{&n,&n};

do j=1 to &n;
  r{1,j} = r_1{j};
end;

do i=2 to &n;
  do j=i to &n;
  r{i,j} = r{i-1,j}/(1-r{i-1,i-1});
end;
```

Am I on the right track?

Comment: Fix you notation please. You are mixing up r_ with r which makes this a bit hard to read. Please use Latex syntax if possible. Also have you attempted anything ?

Comment: @Python R SAS, simply using dollars for Latex does not seem to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure where the input data is coming from. But assuming you have flexibility to name them the way want I tried the following:

```
/* Creating this to have some data to work with. */
/* You may probably populate r1_ elements on the fly within your dataset */

%let n = 5;

data have (keep = r1_:);

  /* This defines r1_1, r1_2 etc. and groups them into array*/
  array r1 {&n} r1_1 - r1_&n;

  /* Generating 5 records to play with */
  do cnt = 1 to 5;
    do ii = 1 to &n;
      r1{ii} = round(ranuni(23423)*10,1);
    end;
    output;
  end;
run;

%let total = %eval(&n * &n);

data want;
  set have;

  /* You need to regroup the r1 elements into an array */
  /* Otherwise SAS will not know how to perform array operation on those group of variables */
  array r1 {&n} r1_1 - r1_&n;

  /* Then you have the 2D array */
  array R {&n,&n} R_1 - R_&total;

  do j = 1 to &n;
    R{1,j} = r1{j};
  end;

  do i = 2 to &n;
    do j = i to &n;
      R{i,j} = R{i-1,j}/(1-R{i-1,i-1});
    end;
  end;
run;
```

Having `R1 - R&total` can be confusing when you are looking at those values since the subscripts are lost.
You can try this way of naming the components for more readability:

```
%macro want;

data want;
  set have;

  /* You need to regroup the r1 elements into an array */
  /* Otherwise SAS will not know how to perform array operation on those group of variables */
  array r1 {&n} r1_1 - r1_&n;

  /* Then you have the 2D array */
  /* The loop just generates components to be named R11 to R15, R21 to R25 etc. instead of just R1 to R25 */
  array R {&n,&n} 
  %do ii = 1 %to &n;
      R_&ii.1 - R_&ii.&n
  %end;
  ;

  do j = 1 to &n;
    R{1,j} = r1{j};
  end;

  do i = 2 to &n;
    do j = i to &n;
      R{i,j} = R{i-1,j}/(1-R{i-1,i-1});
    end;
  end;
run;

%mend;

%want;
```

You may also want to explore `PROC IML` for work like this since it will give you more flexibility in your matrix operations.